# Logstash date parsing error ( date field doesn't have any time)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, datefilter

My data has date in the format yyyy-MM-dd ex : "2015-10-12"

My logstash date filter is as below

```
    input {
            file {
                    path => "/etc/logstash/immport.csv"

                    codec => multiline {
                    pattern => "^S*"
                    negate => true
                    what => "previous"

            }
                    start_position => "beginning"
            }

    }
    filter {
            csv {

                    separator => ","
                    autodetect_column_names => true
                    skip_empty_columns => true
            }

            date {
            match => ["start_date", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
                    target => "start_date"
            }
            mutate {
                 rename => {"start_date" => "[study][startDate]"}
            }

    }
    output {
        elasticsearch {
                action => "index"
                hosts => ["elasticsearch-5-6:9200"]
                index => "immport12"
                document_type => "dataset"
                template => "/etc/logstash/immport-mapping.json"
        template_name => "mapping_template"
        template_overwrite => true
        }

        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

However, my es instance is not able to parse it and I'm getting following error

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [study.startDate]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2012-04-17T00:00:00.000Z\" is malformed at \"T00:00:00.000Z\""}}}}}
```

Sample Data Row
][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"immport_2017_12_02", :_type=>"dataset", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-12-20T08:55:45.367Z 878192e51991 SDY816,HEPSV_COHORT: Participants that received Heplisav,,,2012-04-17,,10.0,Systems Biology Analysis of the response to Licensed Hepatitis B Vaccine (HEPLISAV) in specific cell subsets (see companion studies SDY299 and SDY690),Interventional,http://www.immport.org/immport-open/public/study/study/displayStudyDetail/SDY816,,Interventional,Vaccine Response,Homo sapiens,Cell,DNA microarray], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"immport_2017_12_02", "_type"=>"dataset", "_id"=>"AWBzIsBPov62ZQtaldxQ", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [study.startDate]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2012-04-17T00:00:00.000Z\" is malformed at \"T00:00:00.000Z\""}}}}}

I want my logstash to output date in this format yyyy-MM-dd without timestamp
Mapping template

```
"startDate": {
         "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
 },
```

Comment: Please paste the sample data row by just printing the output by `output { stdout { codec => rubydebug  } }`

Comment: @HatimStovewala I have added sample data row can you let me know what's the issue is ?

Comment: Paste your entire logstash config file.

Comment: @HatimStovewala Added full logstash config file

Comment: Everything seems fine. Is the datatype mapping done in `template` in output elasticsearch? If yes, please paste the json file also. You can also do one thing by explicitly casting/converting each column rather than dynamically allotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I changed the logstash mapping template name to new name, I didn't delete the old template file and hence the index was still pointing to old template file

once I deleted the old template file

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_templates/test_template'
```

it worked, so whenever we are using new template it's required to delete old template and then process records

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on my machine with reference to your logstash conf file and it worked fine.

> My Logstash conf file :

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:\testdata\stack.csv"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^S*"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        autodetect_column_names => true
        skip_empty_columns => true
    }
    date {
        match => ["dob", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
        target => "dob"
    }
    mutate {
        rename => {"dob" => "[study][dob]"}
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "stack"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

> CSV file :

```
id,name,rollno,dob,age,gender,comments
1,hatim,88,1992-07-30,25,male,qsdsdadasd asdas das dasd asd asd asd as dd sa d
2,hatim,89,1992-07-30,25,male,qsdsdadasd asdas das dasd asd asd asd as dd sa d
```

> Elasticsearch document after indexing :

```
{
    "_index": "stack",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "wuBTeGABQ7gwBQSQTX1q",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "path": """D:\testdata\stack.csv""",
        "study": {
            "dob": "1992-07-29T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "@timestamp": "2017-12-21T09:06:52.465Z",
        "comments": "qsdsdadasd asdas das dasd asd asd asd as dd sa d",
        "gender": "male",
        "@version": "1",
        "host": "INMUCHPC03284",
        "name": "hatim",
        "rollno": "88",
        "id": "1",
        "message": "1,hatim,88,1992-07-30,25,male,qsdsdadasd asdas das dasd asd asd asd as dd sa d\r",
        "age": "25"
    }
}
```

And everything worked perfectly. See if this example might help you with something.

Comment: I guess I have issue in template mapping file, I updated post check it once, I don't want timestamp in my es Index